# Android NDK and rendering to live wallpapers

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk

I'm just looking around for starting learning NDK, with one particular project in mind:

I want to continually render a changing bitmap from NDK side to be able to show it in a live wallpaper.

(hence I'm not talking about rendering to OpenGL texture here, but about rendering to a Bitmap)

I googled a bit and found out that there's an option to directly manipulate a Bitmap pixels. But I also found that documentation says that this feature is avaiable only since Android 2.2.
And I'd like to support 2.1 in my live wallpaper.

On the other hand I found several projects that do similar stuff - render something from ndk and show it in live wallpaper. And they work on 2.1. Examples are: wonderful [Video Live Wallpaper](http://android.ccpcreations.com/vlw), and I think [Shake Them All Live Wallpaper](http://www.shake-them-all.net/) does the same kind of stuff.

So the question is - am I missing some other way to do continuous rendering to LW other than direct manipulation of Bitmap data?
Or some other thing I got wrong? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the other projects that do rendering with the NDK and use `jnigraphics`  prior to 2.2 actually include that library in the project and load it as a 3-rd party library.

See the description of `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` in `android-ndk-r5b/docs/ANDROID-MK.html` for more information on how to do that.

You can find jnigraphics in:

```
android-ndk-r5b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/libjnigraphics.so
```

Of course, I don't know if it's actually permissible to redistribute part of the NDK (maybe someone else can weigh in on this), but apparently the only holdup with using `jnigraphics` prior to Android 2.2 is simply the fact that it's not present in earlier releases.

Hope that helps.

Comment: is jnigraphics written in Java? In that case it would make a lot more sense to write it in Java.